# Translation Tool needed: Sort by msgctxt

Tags: sorting, poedit, language-translation

I am looking for a translation software tool that allows columns to be sorted by the msgctxt value.

Here's a screenshot of my poedit .pot file: The msgctxt has been imported, but it is not a sortable value.

[image: poedit screenshot]

This is the generated code:

```
msgctxt "imlang_ext"
msgid "To participate in this challenge please register below."
msgstr "Um am Fotowettbewerb teilnehmen zu können ist es notwendig, daß Sie sich registrieren. "

msgctxt "imlang_msg"
msgid "An error has occured. Please try again later."
msgstr "Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten. Bitte versuchen Sie es zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt erneut."
```

I want to allow translators to quickly get to the strings that vary from client to client (msgctxt: imlang_ext) and leave system messages alone (msgctxt: imlang_msg).

Which software can sort .pot files by msgctxt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eazy Po](http://www.eazypo.ca) can sort messages by different attributes including sorting by message context.

Click the small icon button at the top left corner of the table, or from the main menu; select File -> View then Columns.  A small box will appear listing the following columns:

Reference, Context, Line Number and Text Length.

Select Context and then press OK, additional columns titled “Msg Context” will be added to the main table list. By clicking on the Context column title; the table will be sorted on Message context in ascending order, clicking the same column title again will sort the table on the same column in descending order.

[image: Adding a sortable column in Eazy Po]

Answer (score 0):

Poedit does, in its (not yet released as of today, will be in 1.7) HEAD version:
https://github.com/vslavik/poedit/commit/5fbe45fe9e0d1268ed615f1679dd540cfdf1da9d